AttributeError: 'Blob' object has no attribute '_prep_and_do_upload' When I try to perform add_texts() method in the VectorSearchVectorStore object
I'm trying to build a RAG system using a vector search index from GCP services on Python.
I have already created the vector search index and deployed the endpoint. Im using below code:
from langchain_google_vertexai import (
    VectorSearchVectorStore,
    VectorSearchVectorStoreDatastore,
)
# TODO : replace 1234567890123456789 with your acutial index ID
my_index = aiplatform.MatchingEngineIndex("1234567890123456789")

# TODO : replace 1234567890123456789 with your acutial endpoint ID
my_index_endpoint = aiplatform.MatchingEngineIndexEndpoint("1234567890123456789")

# Input texts
chunk_texts= [
    "The cat sat on",
    "the mat.",
    "I like to",
    "eat pizza for",
    "dinner.",
    "The sun sets",
    "in the west.",
]

# Create a Vector Store
vector_store = VectorSearchVectorStore.from_components(
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    region=REGION,
    gcs_bucket_name=BUCKET,
    index_id=my_index.name,
    endpoint_id=my_index_endpoint.name,
    embedding=embedding_model,
    stream_update=True,
)

# Add vectors and mapped text chunks to your vectore store
vector_store.add_texts(texts=chunk_texts,is_complete_overwrite=True)

Full Error:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-22-5aa9b7d77460> in <cell line: 19>()
     17 
     18 # Add vectors and mapped text chunks to your vectore store
---> 19 vector_store.add_texts(texts=text_chunks,is_complete_overwrite=True)

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain_google_vertexai/vectorstores/vectorstores.py in add_texts(self, texts, metadatas, is_complete_overwrite, **kwargs)
    198         ]
    199 
--> 200         self._document_storage.mset(list(zip(ids, documents)))
    201 
    202         embeddings = self._embeddings.embed_documents(texts)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain_google_vertexai/vectorstores/document_storage.py in mset(self, key_value_pairs)
     98                 # the input list, in order.
     99                 if isinstance(result, Exception):
--> 100                     raise result
    101         else:
    102             for key, value in key_value_pairs:

/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py in run(self)
     56 
     57         try:
---> 58             result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
     59         except BaseException as exc:
     60             self.future.set_exception(exc)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/transfer_manager.py in _call_method_on_maybe_pickled_blob(maybe_pickled_blob, method_name, *args, **kwargs)
   1276     else:
   1277         blob = pickle.loads(maybe_pickled_blob)
-> 1278     return getattr(blob, method_name)(*args, **kwargs)
   1279 
   1280 

AttributeError: 'Blob' object has no attribute '_prep_and_do_upload'

langchain_google_vertexai == 1.0.10
The pipeline works when I create a new vector search and deploy a new endpoint, but I encounter an error when attempting to use it from a prebuilt ID.

Have you tried debugging the code? _prep_and_do_upload very likely doesn't exist (don't know) on (Cloud Storage) Blob. Can you clarify the values you're using for e.g. BUCKET (even if you use an example) and it would be useful to see pip freeze

Hi , Simon could you please provide an update for the above comment ?
